# How to "bootstrap" parent POM in GCP Artifact Registry

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

I followed the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/authentication) to configure a maven client to use an Artifact Registry. I was able to deploy my root pom to it successfully; however, when I have a separate project that inherits from that root pom, it fails to build because it doesn't know where to find the root pom. This makes sense: the child project has no way of knowing that the parent pom is to be found in a random Artifact Registry repo. What is the standard practice for this?

What i've done before is in every programmer's computer, configure the `<repository>` in their `settings.xml` but this doesn't scale well + it needs human intervention + it's very cumbersome when dealing with CI since now you need to configure the settings.xml of the build robot. Considering there's so many CI systems nowadays I imagine there's a convention by now. Is there a better way to accomplish this? some way that's committed in the repo and where everything works right out of the box? git clone... mvn package... done. I ask specifically about Artifact Registry because it doesn't use a static username/password but uses the maven wagon to authenticate

One potential solution is to not put the `<repository>` in the root pom but in every project's pom but that leads to a lot of duplication since the config + the wagon is pretty verbose

Comment: It seems you want to deploy your children POM to Artifacts Registry but it will fail because the parent POM is excluded in deployment, Am I correct?

Comment: no. building the child fails because it references the parent, which lives in Artifact Registry. The parent was deployed successfully. The problem is that every child (every project) references the one and only parent POM, which is in AR, but the configuration of the AR repository is in the parent POM. So catch-22, i can't bootstrap other children projects

Comment: I have a little bit knowledge about java, can you show how can we reproduce this issue? and what is the exactly error that you encountered? It can help us to replicate the issue.

Comment: Hi! Same probleme here. Did you find some solution??

Comment: Kind of: using a .mvn folder with settings.xml and configuring the repository there. But i haven't tried it with a private repo and the weird AR authentication

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your child and parent share a common .mvn/ folder, you can add:

.mvn/extensions.xml:

```xml
<extensions xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/core-extensions-1.0.0.xsd">
    <!--This has to be declared here in order to allow child modules to be able to fetch older parent POMs.-->
    <extension>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.artifactregistry</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactregistry-maven-wagon</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </extension>
    <!--project-settings-extension allows using project-specific .mvn/settings.xml-->
    <extension>
        <groupId>com.github.gzm55.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-settings-extension</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.1</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>
```

.mvn/settings.xml (don't forget to use your actual artifactregistry URL):

```xml
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <!--This has to be declared here in order to allow child modules to be able to fetch older parent POMs.-->
        <repository>
          <id>cloud-artifacts</id>
          <url>artifactregistry://...</url> <!--use actual full URL here-->
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

The repository in settings.xml informs Maven to consider that location when searching for artifacts. The artifactregistry-maven-wagon extension allows Maven to access artifacts via the artifactregistry:// protocol.

The other extension (com.github.gzm55.maven) causes Maven to look at the project-specific settings.xml file (you could also just pass --settings=<*path to file*>, perhaps in .mvn/maven.config, but that would override any user settings).